# Android Resources OpenGLES 2.0 Example Force Closes

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, forceclose

I have just recently started out programming for Android, and have decided that I want to learn how to use OpenGL ES 2.0. I googled around for an example and it turns out that in the resources section of the Android Developers Website there is one.

Link: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html#touch

However, I am trying to run the first example and I get a force-close on my HTC EVO. I have tried literally copy and pasting the code from broswer to Eclipse, and adding the appropriate line in the manifest, but still no dice.

Any help here?

Comment: There should be a Java exception traceback in your logcat. Try looking at that to narrow down where the error is occurring.

Comment: After reading carefully through that, turns out all i had to do was modify the activity in the manifest file. Problem Solved.

Comment: Please put this as the answer to your question to remove it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading carefully through that, turns out all i had to do was modify the activity in the manifest file. Problem Solved.